# How do I get My Code to print out Binary Properly?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, binary, stack

Im Required to use linked Lists and a stack to change decimal to binary but no matter what i enter I get "1" returned in my print statement. can someone please help me?
I have every other function Correct I would need but I can't get anything else but 1

```
51 int tobin(int n)
52 {
53     int num;
54     while( n != 0)
55     {
56         if(!isEmpty)
57         {
58             push(n % 2);
59             n = n / 2;
60         }
61         else
62         {
63             num = pop();
64         }
65         printf("%d");
66     }
67     return num;
68 }
69 int main()
70 {
71     int num;
72     int bin;
73
74     printf("Enter an integer: ");
75     scanf("%d", &num);
76
77     tobin(bin);
78     printf("Binary: %d\n");
79
80     return 0;
81 }
```

Comment: `printf("%d");` You need to tell it what to print, not just that you want a number `(%d)` - same with the printf in main().

Comment: `tobin(bin);` --> `tobin(num);`

Comment: `printf("Binary: %d\n");` print what? , an int parameter is missing

Comment: `tobin(bin);` bin and num, are local variables, where is the relation between them, bin is not set

Comment: your profile photo is inappropriate. please change it

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the value returned from `tobin` and then pass that value to `printf`.

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    int bin;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    bin = tobin(num);
    printf("Binary: %d\n", bin);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The `tobin` method will not correctly handle converting the number `0`. Without seeing the rest of your code to know, I would guess that `tobin` does not convert negative numbers either. You should check the value of the parameter `n` passed in to `tobin` to make sure it is a valid number that your code can handle.

Comment: Should probably also point out that there are other bugs. For example, if `0` is entered then `tobin` will return a junk value as `num` is not intialised in that function. And it also appears to do a `pop` on an empty stack. And even more importantly, don't see how "%d" is going to print in binary format.

Comment: Agreed, there are missing pieces here. He seems interested in getting his converted binary number to print so I answered that question. The `printf` on line 65 would not print out a binary number so it might be there for debugging.